# Как сделать редирект?

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, php, html

Есть у меня в файле *.html php код. где есть ссылка

```
 echo 'img src="rs.ru/images/cat_pic_files/123123.jpg"></a>
```

Должна быть

```
 echo 'img src="rs.ru/images/cat_pic_files/123123.jpg/"></a>
```

Со слешем картинка не видна. Тут понятно - апач ищет папку вместо картинки.

Как сделать, чтобы слеш был (и в url тоже), картинка отображалась, без mod rewrite?

Comment: Мой вам совет - всегда отдавайте картинки с расширением. Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос выложите все правила для url'ов.

Comment: какие правила? mod_rewrite?

Comment: @ferz721 да.

Comment: @lampa чуть ошибка, картинка с расширением. слеш нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(png|jpg|ico)\/$ $1.$2 [R=301,L]
```

Пока придумал только редирект.

Answer (score -1):

```
 echo 'img src="рhttp://rs.ru/images/cat_pic_files/123123.jpg"></a>
```